# Pythagorean Triplet with given sum

Tags: python, pythagorean, triplet

The following code prints the pythagorean triplet if it is equal to the input, but the problem is that it takes a long time for large numbers like 90,000 to answer.
What can I do to optimize the following code?
1 ≤ n ≤ 90 000

```
def pythagoreanTriplet(n):

    # Considering triplets in
    # sorted order. The value
    # of first element in sorted
    # triplet can be at-most n/3.
    for i in range(1, int(n / 3) + 1):

        # The value of second element
        # must be less than equal to n/2
        for j in range(i + 1,
                       int(n / 2) + 1):

            k = n - i - j
            if (i * i + j * j == k * k):
                print(i, ", ", j, ", ",
                      k, sep="")
                return

    print("Impossible")
# Driver Code
vorodi = int(input())
pythagoreanTriplet(vorodi)
```

Comment: If I run this code and enter `90000` it prints `Impossible` immediately and exits.

Comment: you copy / pasted your code from this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythagorean-triplet-given-sum/ -- it has very good explanation, why don't you read it??

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-generate-Pythagorean-triples-given-the-sum-of-the-triples/answer/Bob-Carr-16)

Comment: The code has been modified

Comment: The above code works fine, but works slowly at large input numbers, for example 90,000. How do I change this code to make it faster?

Comment: @PersianGenius--my answer provides code which is several orders of magnitude faster for large n since it's an O(n) rather than o(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [source code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythagorean-triplet-given-sum/) does a brute force search for a solution so it's slow.

**Faster Code**

```
def solve_pythagorean_triplets(n):
  " Solves for triplets whose sum equals n "
  solutions = []
  for a in range(1, n):
    denom = 2*(n-a)
    num = 2*a**2 + n**2 - 2*n*a
    if denom > 0 and num % denom == 0:
      c = num // denom
      b = n - a - c
      if b > a:
        solutions.append((a, b, c))

  return solutions
```

**OP code**

Modified OP code so it returns all solutions rather than printing the first found to compare performance

```
def pythagoreanTriplet(n): 
  
    # Considering triplets in  
    # sorted order. The value  
    # of first element in sorted  
    # triplet can be at-most n/3. 
    results = []
    for i in range(1, int(n / 3) + 1):  
          
        # The value of second element  
        # must be less than equal to n/2 
        for j in range(i + 1,  
                       int(n / 2) + 1):  
  
            k = n - i - j 
            if (i * i + j * j == k * k):
                results.append((i, j, k))
      
    return results
```

**Timing**

```
 n     pythagoreanTriplet (OP Code)     solve_pythagorean_triplets (new)
  900   0.084 seconds                       0.039 seconds
  5000  3.130 seconds                       0.012 seconds
  90000 Timed out after several minutes     0.430 seconds
```

**Explanation**

Function `solve_pythagorean_triplets` is O(n) algorithm that works as follows.

1. Searching for:

   ```
   a^2 + b^2 = c^2 (triplet)
   a + b + c = n   (sum equals input)
   ```
2. Solve by searching over a (i.e. a fixed for an iteration). With a fixed, we have two equations and two unknowns (b, c):

   ```
   b + c = n - a
   c^2 - b^2 = a^2
   ```
3. Solution is:

   ```py
   denom = 2*(n-a)
   num = 2*a**2 + n**2 - 2*n*a
   if denom > 0 and num % denom == 0:
       c = num // denom
       b = n - a - c
       if b > a:
           (a, b, c) # is a solution
   ```
4. Iterate a range(1, n) to get different solutions

**Edit June 2022 by @AbhijitSarkar:**

For those who like to see the missing steps:

```
c^2 - b^2 = a^2
b + c = n - a
=> b = n - a - c

c^2 - (n - a - c)^2 = a^2
=> c^2 - (n - a - c) * (n - a - c) = a^2
=> c^2 - n(n - a - c) + a(n - a - c) + c(n - a - c) = a^2
=> c^2 - n^2 + an + nc + an - a^2 - ac + cn - ac - c^2 = a^2
=> -n^2 + 2an + 2nc - a^2 - 2ac = a^2
=> -n^2 + 2an + 2nc - 2a^2 - 2ac = 0
=> 2c(n - a) = n^2 - 2an + 2a^2
=> c = (n^2 - 2an + 2a^2) / 2(n - a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

DarrylG's answer is correct, and I've added the missing steps to it as well, but there's another solution that's faster than iterating from `[1, n)`. Let me explain it, but I'll leave the code up to the reader.

We use [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) of generating a tuple.

```
a = m^2 - n^2, b = 2mn, c = m^2 + n^2, where m > n > 0 ---(i)
a + b + c = P ---(ii)
```

Combining equations (i) and (ii), we have:

```
2m^2 + 2mn = P ---(iii)
```

Since `m > n > 0`, `1 <= n <= m - 1`.
Putting `n=1` in equation (iii), we have:

```
2m^2 + 2m - P = 0, ax^2 + bx + c = 0, a=2, b=2, c=-P
 m = (-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a
 => (-2 +- sqrt(4 + 8P)) / 4
 => (-1 +- sqrt(1 + 2P)) / 2
```

Since `m > 0`, `sqrt(b^2 - 4ac) > -b`, the only solution is

```
 (-1 + sqrt(1 + 2P)) / 2 ---(iv)
```

Putting `n=m-1` in equation (iii), we have:

```
2m^2 + 2m(m - 1) - P = 0
 => 4m^2 - 2m - P = 0, ax^2 + bx + c = 0, a=4, b=-2, c=-P
 m = (-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a
 => (2 +- sqrt(4 + 16P)) / 8
 => (1 +- sqrt(1 + 4P)) / 4
```

Since `m > 0`, the only solution is

```
(1 + sqrt(1 + 4P)) / 4 ---(v)
```

From equation (iii), `m^2 + mn = P/2`; since `P/2` is constant,
when `n` is the smallest, `m` must be the largest, and vice versa.

Thus:

```
(1 + sqrt(1 + 4P)) / 4 <= m <= (-1 + sqrt(1 + 2P)) / 2 ---(vi)
```

Solving equation (iii) for `n`, we have:

```
 n = (P - 2m^2) / 2m ---(vii)
```

We iterate for `m` within the bounds given by the inequality (vi)
and check when the corresponding `n` given by equation (vii) is
an integer.

Despite generating all primitive triples, Euclid's formula does not
produce all triples - for example, `(9, 12, 15)` cannot be generated using
integer `m` and `n`. This can be remedied by inserting an additional
parameter `k` to the formula. The following will generate all Pythagorean
triples uniquely.

```
a = k(m^2 - n^2), b = 2kmn, c = k(m^2 + n^2), for k >= 1.
```

Thus, we iterate for integer values of `P/k` until `P < 12`,
lowest possible perimeter corresponding to the triple `(3, 4, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

the given function takes array and tells whether there is a pythagoream triplets or not

```
//User function template for C++
class Solution{
public:
    // Function to check if the
    // Pythagorean triplet exists or not
    bool checkTriplet(int arr[], int n) {
        // code here
        
        map<int,int> m;
        int l=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            m[arr[i]]++;
            l=max(l,arr[i]);
        }
        
        for(int i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
            if(m[i]!=0)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<=l;j++)
                {
                    if(m[j]!=0)
                    {
                        int c=sqrt(i*i+j*j);
                        if(c*c==i*i+j*j){if(m[c]!=0) return true;};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
        
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo
I don't know if you still need the answer or not but hopefully, this can help.

```
n = int(input())
ans = [(a, b, c) for a in range(1, n) for b in range(a, n) for c in range(b, n) if (a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and a + b + c == n)]
if ans:
    print(ans[0][0], ans[0][1], ans[0][2])
else:
    print("Impossible")
```